# How to use alter table drop columns for columns present in a list?

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, alter-table, snowsql

I have a list of all column names to be dropped from multiple tables in a schema, but not all the column names in the list have it's presence in all the tables.

For the schema and the table name I have can I in a single query do a check if the columns match the column names in the list just drop that

Say the column list to drop is

```
Drop_col = ['AB',' BC', FG', 'TR']
```

But my TABLE1 has only  'BC', 'TR' in the column list

```
Query =  ALTER TABLE SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE1 DROP COLUMN IN ({Drop}).format (Drop = Drop_col)
```

Something Like this?? or any other suggestions ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use COLUMNS view and Stored Procedure to achieve this.

1- Pass the list of columns in stored procedure

2- Using COLUMNS view Get the list of table, column results

3-Iterate on the resultset and drop columns

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/columns.html

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-scan-Result-set-in-stored-procedures

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Select-columns-based-on-condition-in-Snowflake-using-Information-Schema-and-Stored-Procedure

Comment: I do not want to use stored procedures